# How to only change specific vertex position of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I plot a graph using the following specifications:

```
GraphPlot[
    $edges,
    GraphLayout->{"LayeredDigraphEmbedding","Orientation"->Left}
]
```

Suppose I am happy with the automatic coordinates chosen by the system except for one and I want to translate that by say `+{1,2}`.

`GraphPlot` has an option called `VertexCoordinates` but it requires me to give all the coordinates explicitly but I just want to modify one of them.

One way I found was to `Sow` the automatically chosen coordinates using `Sow[#1]` in option `VertexShapeFunction` then `Reap` them out to a variable then perform the translation I want to the coordinates outside then rerun the `GraphPlot` with modified `VertexCoordinates`.

This is cumbersome there must be a better way to accept all automatically generated coordinates but translate some of them to the better location. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use `GraphPlot` instead of `Graph`?

Comment: Make a `Graph`, extract coordinates with `GraphEmbedding`, modify the one you want, re-insert with the `VertexCoordinates` option.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am using complex `EdgeShapeFunction` & `VertexShapeFunction` conditions and there is an `Epilog` as well. I don't think I can have all this flexibility with a basic `Graph`. I am basically building a complex flowchart. Moreover If I have to exact the coordinates and reinsert them, then this is precisely what I am trying to avoid. Is there a coordinate modification function of some sort?

Comment: "I don't think I can have all this flexibility with a basic Graph." This is not true. You should use `Graph` unless you actually found (rather than merely suspected) a reason why it is not suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `Graph`, not `GraphPlot`, unless there is a very good reason not to. `Graph` stores an actual graph, with metadata, in a structured way. `GraphPlot` merely produces graphics, with all structures information getting lost.

You can manipulate the metadata in a graph using the `Property*` functions such as [`PropertyValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html). These functions tend to be tricky to use and (unfortunately) often inconsistent. But for this purpose, they work straightforwardly.

The following example makes use of my IGraph/M package for convenience, but you do not need to rely on it.

We generate a random tree, and set our preferred layout method:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

SeedRandom[123]
g = IGTreeGame[6, DirectedEdges -> True, GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold", 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

There are no stored vertex coordinates in this graph right now. They are computed, not stored, therefore they cannot be modified. To modify them, we must store them first. With IGraph/M, I'd do:

```
g = IGVertexMap[# &, VertexCoordinates, g]
```

but without it you can also do:

```
g = Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

Now we can modify the coordinate of a single vertex:

```
PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexCoordinates] += {-1, 2}
```

Show the graph:

```
g
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you `Graph` is working fine. Just I had to change the `$edge` format from `{{"v1"->"v2","label"}, ...}` to `Labeled@@@{{"v1"->"v2","label"}, ...}`. I just hope I will be able to get a high quality `eps` file in the end from the `Graph` object just like I can get it from the `Graphics` generated by `GraphPlot`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: In the graph above `g`, after you find the coordinates of the vertices; (1) fix the coordinates of `g`, (2) delete vertex `2` from `g`; (3) get the new graph without `2` while keeping the vertex coordinates unchanged. This will allow me to compare two graphs: before and after vertex deletion. How do you do that?

Comment: @TugrulTemel You mean how to compare? You can set the same `PlotRange` on both and use `FlipView`? Maybe I misunderstood. I may not be logged in much, so if I don't respond, please ping me in a few days.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your reply. I have a directed graph with 5 vertices. First, I want to fix the coordinates of the 5 vertices in the graph. Then, delete one of the vertices from the graph. Finally, I simply want to visually compare the two graphs to see what is lost in the latter graph.

Comment: @TugrulTemel That's exactly what is shown in my answer above. Just forget about this line: `PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexCoordinates] += {-1, 2}` and use only the rest.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your answer. It worked, but then `EdgeWeight`s are mixed up when I delete one of the vertices. These weights and edges should be preserved in the original format. Is there a special way to fix the edges and their weights?

Comment: @TugrulTemel What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @Szabolcs: MMA v11.3, windows 7.

Comment: @TugrulTemel The graph functionality in Mathematica is still quite buggy. In 11.3, it's no exaggeration to say that it's unusable. As you can see a simple deletion of a vertex will mess everything up. Now you know why my fuse blew at some point and made me write this: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1321057

Comment: @Szabolcs: It is really sad that we are left with buggy Graph. Now I am going to ask a question about the edgeweight fixing problem. I hope someone will answer. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 6):

**Update for Mathematica 12.1+**: If you want to fix positions of some vertices and have the rest positioned automatically, we can now use `VertexCoordinates`, e.g.

```
Graph[
  {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {1, 1}}
]
```

See [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html)

Comment: Major versions of Mathematica are (effectively) of the form `x.y`, not of the form `x`. Please avoid using the latter, as it regularly confuses people. This works in 12.1 and does not work in 12.0. I am not even sure why Wolfram still uses the `x.y` form since I don't see a much bigger difference between e.g. 11.3 and 12.0 than 12.0 and 12.1.  (Otherwise +1 for pointing out this useful feature.)

Comment: I went ahead and changed 12 to 12.1 in your answer. I hope that's okay with you.

Comment: @Szabolcs Nobody seems to care for [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) these days and everything is driven by [Marketing](https://wiki2.org/en/Software_versioning+Brights.4#Version_numbers_as_marketing). At least with `v13.0` coming up we are obviously spared irrational `superstitious versioning`. ;-)